# 'DataFrame' object without attribute error

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to run a basic from-scratch code for linear regression. It is giving me this error despite the csv file containing a column header with the following name "studytime" for which it is giving me this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/brasilgu/Downloads/student/student-por.csv')
plt.scatter(data.studytime, data.score)
plt.show
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your data with

```
print(data.columns)
```

to ensure you have no typos etc. if not you'll need to put an example of the data in to reproduce.

Comment: So I ran that command and its displaying the column "failures" and "studytime." I got the dataset from this website https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance. It is in Data Folder>student.zip>student-por.csv

Comment: just show output of ````data.head()````?

Comment: sure school;sex;age;address;famsize;Pstatus;Medu;Fedu;Mjob;Fjob;reason;guardian;traveltime;studytime;failures;schoolsup;famsup;paid;activities;nursery;higher;internet;romantic;famrel;freetime;goout;Dalc;Walc;health;absences;G1;G2;G3